# Running a service ignores environment variables

Tags: node.js, service, environment-variables, ubuntu-12.04

I have a /ect/init/application.conf file that looks something like...

```
start on filesystem and net-device-up IFACE!=lo
stop on runlevel [016]
respawn

export NODE_ENV=production

chdir /home/richie/application
exec /home/richie/.nvm/v0.10.26/bin/node server/app >> /var/log/node.log 2>&1
```

It is meant to run a Node.js application in production mode. However, when I run the application as a service:

```
sudo service application start
```

It outputs this data in the log when I output my environment variables:

```
{ UPSTART_INSTANCE: '',
  UPSTART_JOB: 'application',
  TERM: 'linux',
  PATH: '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin',
  PWD: '/home/richie/application' }
```

As you can see, NODE_ENV does not exist in the list of environment variables. Any idea why my exported environment variable would be ignored? I also have added into my /etc/environment file:

```
NODE_ENV=production
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try  using 'env' instead of 'export'

Comment: Duplicate answered here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/440407/running-a-service-ignores-environment-variables